# Why am I getting an 'ImportError: symbol not found' when importing manim in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, manim

```
(base) debruppaul@Debrups-MacBook-Air ~ % manim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/bin/manim", line 5, in <module>
    from manim.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .animation.composition import *
  File "/Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/animation/composition.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..scene.scene import Scene
  File "/Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/scene/scene.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ..camera.camera import Camera
  File "/Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/camera/camera.py", line 16, in <module>
    import cairo
  File "/Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_cairo_append_path'
```

This is the error that comes up.

```
and also my path
(base) debruppaul@Debrups-MacBook-Air ~ % pip3 -V
pip 22.3.1 from /Users/debruppaul/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

I tried installing multiple times shows succes full,but while calling shows this error

Comment: Please spend some time learning how to format questions, you'll get a much quicker response that way. I'll help yout out with this one ...